# Gradle sync fails - play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

After adding the " implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0' " Library I'm having this issue. I tried upgrading each dependency to their latest version but no luck.

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Here is my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hussain.podcastapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    def room_version = "1.1.1"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.devlight.navigationtabstrip:navigationtabstrip:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:glidepalette:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.6.1'
    implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:6.0.9"
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The dependencies are updated with their latest versions.

Comment: set `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

In the bottom of the `build.gradle` right after:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Check [this link](https://gist.github.com/jkasten2/2c63ce79c03cac4943e240a46cea218c#file-build-gradle-L45-L47),

And [this link](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/37) too. It might have the same issue with the version.